# How to handle the ECONNRESET error in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using nodejs as a backend and postgres as my database.It works fine for few minutes after starting the server.But,after few minutes it get's crashed and resulting the following error,

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at Connection.connectedErrorHandler (D:\panda_new_1\fishfarmiot\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:221:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (D:\panda_new_1\fishfarmiot\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:57:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-01T11_23_58_697Z-debug.log
```

My connectionstring is,

```
var config = {
    db: {
      
        connectionString: 'postgresql://localhost'
    },
```

My code is,

```
let connectionString = config.db.connectionString;
const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

router.post('/addAlert', (req, res) => {
    var sql = "SELECT public.alert_insert('[" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "]')"
    client.query(sql)
        .then(users => res.status(200).json({ message: "Created Successfully", status: 200 }))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ message: "SomeThing Went Wrong", status: 500 }))
}
)
router.put('/editAlert', (req, res) => {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM alert_edit('" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "'::jsonb)"
    client.query(sql)
        .then(users => res.status(200).json({ message: "Updated Successfully", status: 200 }))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ message: "Id Not Found", status: 404 }))
}
)
router.post('/getAll', (req, res) => {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM alert_getall('" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "'::jsonb);"
    client.query(sql)
        .then(users => res.status(200).send(users.rows))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err))
}
)
router.delete('/deleteAlert', (req, res) => {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM alert_delete('" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "'::jsonb);"
    client.query(sql)
        .then(users => res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted Successfully", status: 200 }))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).son({ message: "Id Not Found", status: 404 }))
}
)
module.exports = router
```

can anyone suggest me, how to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to separate your db connect and controllers function
then make a wrapper around combination of `client.connect();` and `query` to throw global error in your server app and finally catch them with a `middleware`

For example

```js
// db.js
let connectionString = config.db.connectionString;
const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

module.exports.query = function(sql, callback)
client.query(sql)
      .then(result => callback(result)}))
      .catch(err => throw err))
```

```js
// router
const client = require('db.js')
router.post('/addAlert', (req, res) => {
    var sql = "SELECT public.alert_insert('[" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "]')"
    client.query(sql ,(users)=> res.status(200).json({ message: "Created Successfully", status: 200 }))
}
)
```

```js
// server
...
// dbErrorHanler -> function to check db errors
app.user(dbErrorHanler);
...
```